# MFC chtmlview Windows 7 issue

Tags: windows-7, mfc

I am working on an old MFC project. Users are using Windows 7 they are expierincing the following problem which does not occur on Windows XP:

The MFC application hosts a CHtmlView which presents a custom HTML site located as a file on the disk. This html document heavily uses Javascript. Wenn you start the program and the CHtmlView control is displayed, in some cases - for example after a fresh reboot - the HTML file is not properly displayed.

Refreshing the site using F5 or minimizing the application and maximizing it again solves this issue.

I know that CHtmlView is using an ActiveX Control and thus I have tried to change system settings for IE. But this did not solve the problem altogether. The issue after a reboot still remains.

All help is appreciated.

If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running Internet Explorer 9.0 on the problematic client? They changed some of the `WM_PAINT` logic as of that version, so I think you need at least MFC 10.0 to avoid weird drawing artifacts.

I've heard about similar issues before, but I'm still just guessing here :)

Comment: IE 9 was installed on most system. I have check whether thhe problem also exists prior to IE9...

Comment: That actually seems to be the problem. Thank you very much. I don't know if I can ugrade from MFC 6 to MFC 10 easily. That would probably mean that I also have to use VS 2010.